# summation of uneven-sized columns in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum

I have csv file and its content is as follows:

```
a       b
ca  12, 20, 45
ca  18, 27
ca  30, 32, 41, 49
ny  4, 12, 12, 37, 43
ny  33
ny  8, 10, 40, 44
```

How can I read the data into python as pandas DataFrame and obtain the mean and sum value for each row?

Summation example

```
a    b
ca  72
    45
    152
ny  108
    33
    102
```

Comment: what is separator of `a` and `b` columns? `tab` ?

Comment: That is not really a well-structured CSV file.  If there's no comma between "ca" and "12", then they're not separate values in the CSV file.  Also, it doesn't usually make sense to use pandas for data that is not tabular in nature, and yours isn't because your rows are different lengths.

Answer (score 1):

It is not easy, because not well-structured `csv` as pointed [`BrenBarn`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41995712/summation-of-uneven-sized-columns-in-pandas-dataframe#comment71168451_41995712).

Solution:

Main problem is you dont know number of columns, what need add to parameter `names` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for avoid `error`, so you have to use some constant like `N = 20`:

> CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 4, saw 5

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u""" a    b
ca  12, 20, 45
ca  18, 27
ca  30, 32, 41, 49
ny  4, 12, 12, 37, 43
ny  33
ny  8, 10, 40, 44
"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
N = 20
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep="\s+", names = range(N), skiprows = 1)
#print (df)
```

```
#create index from first column, remove all NaN columns, cast to str
df = df.set_index(0).rename_axis('a').dropna(axis=1, how='all').astype(str)
#remove all , and spaces, cast to float
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip(' ,')).astype(float)
#sum and if necessary cast to int
df1 = df.sum(axis=1).astype(int).rename('b').reset_index()
print (df1)
    a    b
0  ca   77
1  ca   45
2  ca  152
3  ny  108
4  ny   33
5  ny  102

#if need spaces
mask = df1.a != df1.a.shift()
df1.a = df1.a.where(mask,'')

print (df1)
    a    b
0  ca   77
1       45
2      152
3  ny  108
4       33
5      102
```

---

More dynamic solution:

```
#get max count of space separators
data = []
with open('file.csv') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        data.append(len(line.split()))

#if necessary add 1
N = max(data)
print (N)
6

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep="\s+",  skiprows = 1, names = range(N))
print (df)
    0    1    2    3    4     5
0  ca  12,  20,   45  NaN   NaN
1  ca  18,   27  NaN  NaN   NaN
2  ca  30,  32,  41,   49   NaN
3  ny   4,  12,  12,  37,  43.0
4  ny   33  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
5  ny   8,  10,  40,   44   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

***setup***

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

txt = """a       b
ca  12, 20, 45
ca  18, 27
ca  30, 32, 41, 49
ny  4, 12, 12, 37, 43
ny  33
ny  8, 10, 40, 44"""
```

***solution***
read the file with a delimiter of `\s{2,}` which specifies two or more spaces.  This will split into `a` and `b` columns.  Then we can deal with `b` afterwards.

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep='\s{2,}', engine='python', index_col=0)
df = df.b.str.split(',\s*', expand=True).astype(float) \
       .sum(1).astype(int).to_frame(name='b')

print(df)

      b
a      
ca   77
ca   45
ca  152
ny  108
ny   33
ny  102
```